# How to get pipeline run id from within ADFv2 pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory

Is there any way to access run id of a running pipeline from within that very pipeline? I haven't found any system variable or function that would return this value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@pipeline().RunId   variable should help you. Refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-system-variables#pipeline-scope  for all variables which you can use in a pipeline.